# Reduce jQuery append method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this the simplest way to write this? This code evaluates if a textbox value exceeds 20 characters, and then displays the proper message (essentially truncating the string and then adding an ellipses to the end.)

I've tried using a tertiary operator but doesn't seem to work with appending data to an element as it overwrites what was previously appended.)

```
if (searchBoxValue.length > numCharToDisplay) {
    searchDropDown.append('<div class="noresults"><span>Searching "' +
    searchBoxValue.trim().substring(0, numCharToDisplay) +
    '..." Found No Results</span></div>');
} else {
    searchDropDown.append('<div class="noresults"><span>Searching "' +
    searchBoxValue.trim() + '" Found No Results</span></div>');
}
```

Comment: Please stop editing your post to add more code and to ask for more reviews; you are invalidating old answers. [Read the help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for every site SE site, please.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing `append` two times, why don't `append` a single time with two different values depending on the length of `searchBox`?

Also, moving the trimmed search value into a variable simplifies the code a bit.

```
var text,
    trimmedSearch = searchBoxValue.trim();
if (searchBoxValue.length > numCharToDisplay) {
    text = '<div class="noresults"><span>Searching "' +
    trimmedSearch.substring(0, numCharToDisplay) +
    '..." Found No Results</span></div>';
} else {
    text = '<div class="noresults"><span>Searching "' +
    trimmedSearch + '" Found No Results</span></div>';
}
searchDropDown.append(text);
```

Using ternary operators, as you suggested, wouldn't be a good practice since it complicates things up, leaving maintenance really difficult.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with Tiago Marinho, I believe that this could be taken a step further.

---

Look at both your appends: that are appending the *exact same string*. Therefore, we can just store this in a variable:

```
var text = "<div class='noresults'></span>Search '";
```

---

I disagree with Tiago Marinho's point about ternary operators, however. I don't believe that it will have any negative impact on your code.

With good formatting, this can actually make your code look rather nice, in my opinion:

```
var trimmedSearch = searchBoxValue.length > numCharToDisplay ?
                    searchBoxValue.trim().substring(0, numCharToDisplay)  + "...'":
                    searchBoxValue.trim();
```

---

All that's left is adding the final "Found No Results" string. Here is the entire code now.

```
var text = "<div class='noresults'></span>Search '";
var trimmedSearch = searchBoxValue.length > numCharToDisplay ?
                    searchBoxValue.trim().substring(0, numCharToDisplay) + "...'":
                    searchBoxValue.trim();

searchDropDown.append(text + trimmedSearch + "' Found no results</span></div";
```

Comment: Wow, you posted your answer at the same time I updated mine. hah

Comment: I'll roll back my edit, because you posted it first. (and also because I haven't noticed that `"...'"` difference between strings)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Could you check my edit above and provide your critique.

Comment: @Jrags87 While I would love to, alas, I cannot. As you see, Jamal has rolled back your edit because you have broken rules found in the help center. Please read there on what you may and may not do after receiving answers.